# ReSharper says that Console.ReadLine() returns null value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I noticed that ReSharper suggests me to check `Console.ReadLine()` for null. I don't understand why, because as far as I know the method returns `""` even if you press `enter` in a console and don't enter any symbol.

I use VS 2015 with the 3rd update, C# 6, .NET 4.6.1, ReSharper 10.

[image]

Comment: In C#6 you could write: `int? length = Console.ReadLine()?.Length;`. Then resharper would be happy and you could handle the case that `!length.HasValue`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That's true. But he was asking *why* ReSharper thinks that `Console.ReadLine()` could be null.

Comment: @diiN_: yes, and you've answered this perfectly. That's why it's only a comment ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) specifies that returning null is part of the contract for this method:

> The next line of characters from the input stream, or **null if no more lines are available**.

And goes onto give an example:

> If the Ctrl+Z character is pressed when the method is reading input from the console, **the method returns null**.

As a further example, you can change the `TextReader` used for `Console.In` using `Console.SetIn`. Your `TextReader` could return null when `ReadLine` is called.

Answer (score 7):

`Console.ReadLine()` can be `null` if you enter Ctrl + Z.

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the Ctrl+Z character is pressed when the method is reading input from the console, the method returns null. This enables the user to prevent further keyboard input when the ReadLine method is called in a loop.

Comment: Amazing example, because can be checked very quickly!

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), if you have redirected standard input to be from a file, `Console.ReadLine()` will return `null` when there are no lines remaining to be read from the file.