# Is there a way to fix my program to resolve 'Converting null Literal to non-nullable type' in C#?

Tags: c#

[image: error]My goal in this program is to allow the user to change the values in a operation and find the area(basically useless calculator) of the rectangle. The results i would expect(from python exp.) is that is woulld read the line and convert it into `int`, then i could multiply the two variables to get the area. Whenever I have tried this, the Error CS8600('Converting null literal to non-nullable type') in line 10(`string name = Console.ReadLine();`) I first thought that it could be some problem with the conversion to integer(**Spare** me, i am very new to this language and Object Oriented Programming in general.) I have not found solutions that i can understand online and am resorting to *Stack Overflow*.
Here's the code, please help me:

```
namespace world
{
    class Username
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)/* by accident i wrote public*/
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is your name? ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Your name is " + name);
            Console.WriteLine("Now about rectangles...");
            Console.WriteLine("Length = ");
            string inlength = Console.ReadLine()??string.Empty;
            int length;
            Int32.TryParse(inlength, out length);
            Console.WriteLine("Width = ");
            string inwidth = Console.ReadLine()??string.Empty;
            int width;
            Int32.TryParse(inwidth, out width);
            int area = length * width;
            Console.WriteLine(area);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably have settings so that nullability must be handled. You could turn that off (project settings, I think) or you will have to mark the string as nullable since `Console.ReadLine()` may return a null.

Comment: I am using VS code in mac, how can i locate this @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: No need to disable nullable reference types. That would not solve the underlying problem that `Console.ReadLine` could return null.     
Replace `var inlength = Console.ReadLine();` by `string inlength = Console.ReadLine()??string.Empty;`.    
Of course you could still get exceptions trying to parse the inut to an integer if invalid input is given.

Comment: @JohanDonne the error is still being given in ```string name = Console.ReadLine();``` in line 10. Same error

Comment: I have replaced the part of code

Comment: oh wait.. no worries

Comment: In terminal the terminal just doesn't want to to do the part after "what is your name

Comment: anyone to save moi

Comment: Edit your question to show your new code.

Comment: You have NOT edited `string name = Console.ReadLine();` which where the error is.

Comment: @PoulBak y'all missed the 'public void' instead of 'static void'

Answer (score 2):

- `null` in C# is *similar* (though far from identical) to `null` in other languages like JavaScript [or `None` in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289601/referring-to-the-null-object-in-python).
- Your `string name` statement declares a variable named `name` of type `non-nullable System.String`

  - The `string` keyword in C# is an alias for the `System.String` type.
- However, the `Console.ReadLine()` method has a return-type of `nullable System.String` (i.e. `string?`).

  - [`Console.ReadLine()` returns `null` if a user presses <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> in a Windows console window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370565/resharper-says-that-console-readline-returns-null-value).
- Therefore, you need to consider how your program will behave in the event the user presses <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> while at the "[What is your name?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWS8Mg-JWSg)" prompt.
- The *quick-fix* is to disregard <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> input and treat it the same as empty-input, in which case the use of `?? String.Empty` (or just `?? ""`) is perfectly fine, and is what you're already doing in the rest of your program already.

Comment: You all missed the 'public void' instead of 'static void' ()

Comment: @JebKerman `static void` is fine. Non-static `public void` won’t work: `Main` must be static.