# Is it okay warnings in c# or should I do something?

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, warnings, nullable

My code works properly but every time when i run the code I have warning which I can not understand.
I run the code in my linux terminal it says: **Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type**
Is it normal? Or should I do something?
Here is my code:

```
namespace test2;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Choose option: \n1. +\n2. -\n3. *\n4. /");
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        string ext = Console.ReadLine();
        if(num == 1){
            while(true){
                Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers or tap Q to exit:");
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int z = x + y;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}+{1}={2}", x,y,z);
            if(ext =="Q"){
                break;
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to write ext inside while loop but I can't

Comment: I guess it is because, Console.ReadLine() is nullable. Here is a link that explains it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370565/resharper-says-that-console-readline-returns-null-value. Also in future, give the exact line where you get a warning, it greatly helps to identify the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReSharper says that Console.ReadLine() returns null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370565/resharper-says-that-console-readline-returns-null-value)

Answer (score 1):

The [warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS8600)#possible-null-assigned-to-a-nonnullable-reference) is to tell you that the right side expression could return a null value and in your case, the left side of the variable is not nullable.

Refer the declaration of [Console.ReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=net-7.0), it returns `string?`.

so you can declare it like  `string? ext = Console.ReadLine();` to get rid of this warning.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a variable with a null default like

```
int? num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: [Convert.ToInt32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32) will always return an int, not a nullable int.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is related to assigning a nullable type to nun-nullable type. A simple alternative is to use `int.tryparse()` method like this:

```
int num;
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  replacing **Convert.ToInt32** with
**int.Parse**

Comment: [Convert.ToInt32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32) is not the culprit here, it can handle a null input gracefully (returning 0).

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did to fix your code a little bit I put the condition inside the while loop and also you forgot to update ext after every iterration additionally I changed the method of getting the input of int to int.Parse instead of your Convert.ToInt32. try this and I am sure it will work as intended.

```
Console.WriteLine("Choose option: \n1. +\n2. -\n3. *\n4. /");
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (num == 1)
        {
            string ext = Console.ReadLine();
            while (!ext.Equals("Q"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers or tap Q to exit:");
                int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                int z = x + y;
                Console.WriteLine("{0}+{1}={2}", x, y, z);
                ext = Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
```